# с# как сделать так, чтобы одновременно показывалась только часть формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим есть форма 1500 на 1200. Как сделать так, чтобы при движении курсора показывался только участок формы скажем 300 на 300 вокруг него?

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)  // этот участок отвечает за черный круг
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        SetEventHandlers(this);
    }
    private void SetEventHandlers(Control ct)
    {
        ct.Paint += PaintControl;
        ct.MouseMove += (o, e) => Invalidate(true);
        foreach (Control item in ct.Controls)
        {
            SetEventHandlers(item);
        }
    }

    int Radius = 100;

    void PaintControl(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;

        Control ct = (Control)sender;
        Point ct_position = ct.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        Point client_position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        int shiftX = ct_position.X - client_position.X;
        int shiftY = ct_position.Y - client_position.Y;
        Point p = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        p.Offset(-shiftX, -shiftY);
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(-shiftX, -shiftY, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height));
            path.AddEllipse(p.X - Radius, p.Y - Radius, 2 * Radius, 2 * Radius);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);  // этот участок отвечает за черный круг
        }
    }
```

Comment: а остальная часть в это время где будет?

Comment: Ну например окно формы уменьшится до тех же 300 на 300 пикселей

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить такое решение.

Размещаем на форме непрозрачную панель поверх всех контролов.

При движении мыши вырезаем в этой панели дырку-регион нужного размера и формы.

Единственная проблема - глобальное отслеживание движения мыши. Я сделал это с помощью таймера - костылик, да, зато просто.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    fogPanel = new Panel { Parent = this, BackColor = Color.Black, Size = this.DisplayRectangle.Size };
    fogPanel.BringToFront();

    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 10;
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var point = PointToClient(MousePosition);
    var rect = new Rectangle(point.X - 50, point.Y - 50, 100, 100);
    var region = new Region(fogPanel.DisplayRectangle);
    region.Exclude(rect);
    fogPanel.Region = region;
}
```

Работает без лагов, плавно, процессор не грузится.

Comment: Не хватает репутации для того, чтобы поставить плюс. Вы мне очень помогли, долгое время мучался с этим вопросом, а решение оказалось очень и очень простым, спасибо!

Comment: @Georg96 но принять ответ вы же можете)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как в WinForms, но в WPF сделать это очень просто с помощью `CombinedGeometry` в режиме `Exclude`.

Разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="400" Height="300"
        MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 6</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 8</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 9</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Элемент 10</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button>Кнопка 1</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 2</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 3</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 4</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 5</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 6</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 7</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 8</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 9</Button>
            <Button>Кнопка 10</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="LightGray"
              Name="path">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 400 300"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="el" Center="50 50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Обработчик события:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    el.Center = e.GetPosition(path);
}
```

[image: Exclude]

Comment: В WPF не работал никогда, в windows forms реализовывал такое, но всё очень сильно лагало

Comment: @Алексей, к счастью, WPF не использует GDI/GDI+ как WinForms, вместо этого используется аппаратное ускорение (DirectX), поэтому производительность не страдает, всё работает очень плавно и быстро, с минимальной нагрузкой на CPU

Comment: Добавил код, который реализовал в winforms, внешне выглядит также, но при быстрых движениях очень сильно лагает. Видимо лучшим решением будет изучить WPF

Comment: Cпасибо за совет