# Как показать лишь часть окна?

Tags: c#, winforms

Возникла необходимость показывать пользователю лишь часть приложения - формы. Как это реализовать, не меняя саму форму и её размеры?

По курсовой работе разрабатываю игру, карта спроектирована вручную, без автоматической генерации через всякие map'ы, и необходимо чтобы была камера слежения за игроком, т.е. чтобы игроку показывалась лишь малая часть карта - та, где он сейчас находится.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: игра на винформах 

Comment: нарисуйте черные прямиоугольники вокруг видимой области

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739328/184217

Comment: Нет, вы меня не поняли.
Мне нужно, чтобы был эффект "Zoom'a", т.е. не образный "туман" в виде черных прямоугольников.
Поставлю вопрос иначе - есть в WinForms возможность приближения/отдаления от какой-то точки?